# How to output a Tcl procedure into a file

Tags: tcl

```
proc my_proc {} {
    puts "Hello World!"
}
```

How do I output this proc contents to a file? I know 'info body my_proc' can print the contents on the screen. I have tried the following but no luck.

```
redirect [info body my_proc] > filename.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `[puts]`:

```
set f [open filename.txt w]
puts $f [info body my_proc]
close $f
```

> I know 'info body my_proc' can print the contents on the screen.

`[info]` is not an I/O command. It serves for introspection and returns the body script ("proc contents") of a Tcl procedure as a string. `[puts]` then "prints" a given string value to an I/O channel.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to (mostly) recreate the proc, try this:

```
set procname "my_proc"
set procedure [list proc $procname [info args $procname] [info body $procname]]
puts $procedure
```

I say "mostly" because `info args` does not emit any default values for the arguments. For that, see https://core.tcl.tk/tips/doc/trunk/tip/65.md that I wrote and abandoned (shockingly) 17 years ago.